Airflow @task decorator not having the correct order
I'm trying the new TaskFlow API
I have 4 @task then I would love to have at the end t1 >> t2 >> t3 >>> t4.
I endup doing :
t1 = task1()
t2 = task2(t1)
t3 = task3(t2)
t4 = task4(t2)

t2.set_downstream(t3)
t3.set_downstream(t4)

But the result is :

I wanted a straight line

you have to do it in the following way:
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from pendulum import datetime

@dag(start_date=datetime(2024, 12, 1), catchup=False, schedule=None)
def temp():
    @task
    def t1():
        print(1)
    
    @task
    def t2(t1_op):
        print(2)

    @task
    def t3(t2_op):
        print(3)

    @task
    def t4(t3_op):
        print(4)
    
    t4(t3(t2(t1())))

temp()


i need the return of t2 (XCOM) as argument in t3 and t4.

If you need the return of t2 as input to t4 then it will not be a straight line, since t4 depends on both t3 and t2. What you can do is have t3 return a more complex output which also includes the output of t2. But I do think the result you got really reflects correctly the dependencies and the logic you have, I would not pursue it.
